# Mysql order by not working properly

Tags: mysql, database

I am using simple `order by` clause to show products according to available quantity

Below is the  query I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM productsinfo ORDER BY quantity desc
```

Query giving no error but sorting order is not correct.Anyone please tell me where I am wrong.

**EDIT**

Have checked my quentity clumn is `varchar` type.I am storing values in `1,215 10,456` format.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Perhaps some sample table data and query output?

Comment: What is the output and how is your table (especially `quantity`) defined?

Comment: could you give us the data type of quantity?

Comment: What does the table definition look like.  Run "SHOW CREATE TABLE productsinfo" so we can see how the columns are defined.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you wrote `ROM` instead of `FROM` you should provide more information. Add the creation scripts of that table, show us some sample date in it and, of course, add the ordering you're expecting to get. Thanks.

Comment: My quantity column is of varchar type

Comment: @nikhil: Why? Your columns should be appropriately typed; quantity is numeric, and you should use the appropriate numeric type for it.

Comment: @nikhil: [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) is king. This question could do with a good dose of table schema and sample data (in the form of SQL statements), along with desired and actual results. Note just about every question requires the same: code, what you want/expect, what you actually have.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Might be your quantity column is `varchar` type so it's not sorting as numbers.Please check.
You need to cast it in integer type

Try below:

```
SELECT * FROM productsinfo ORDER BY CAST(quantity AS UNSIGNED ) desc
```

OR Use below trick.

```
SELECT * FROM productsinfo ORDER BY quantity+0 DESC
```

Comment: Also note that the CAST(quantity AS unsigned) will cause any indexes on quantity to not be used, as functions on columns cause index invalidation (that is unless you create a function based index on CAST(quantity AS unsigned), but that the most efficient solution). The most efficient solution would be to store qty as a numeric value, rather than a varchar, and leave the 'comma' formatting up to the presentation layer.

Answer (score 3):

I think you define quantity as `VarChar`. Because if it's a `Number` (*int*, *smallint*, *decimal*,..) the order will be definitely correct.

```
SELECT *, CAST(quantity AS int) QuantityA 
FROM productsinfo   
ORDER BY QuantityA desc
```

Comment: I had `'FB','IN','TW','VM','WP','LD'` as enum, wow this cast work like charm, and I came to know mysql `enum` sort data in order it has data, not like char, so without cast it will show just reverse `'LD','WP','VM','TW','IN','FB'`. so after using cast I get correct order `'FB', 'IN', 'LD', 'TW', 'VM', 'WP'`

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to first remove the `,` from the value and turn the result into a number. Give this a try:

```
SELECT * FROM productsinfo
ORDER BY REPLACE(quantity, ',', '')+0 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The exect answer is:-
for varchar data type it compares integert data from left to right that means it treat 100 less the the 11.
So thats why comparing and sorting on varchar data type for integer data is a bad choice.
Convert it to int using cast in a query or alter your table.